# Warning: unexpected character in input: " (ascii=29) state=0 in

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

I've been reading about what others have done with this error and have made changes to my php.ini file, added code to override another php setting, and still end up with this same error. Here is my code:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <table>

 <?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>

 <?php

     function getRecords($query) {
         $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "movie", "moviepw");
         if (!$con)
         {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         }

         mysql_select_db("movies", $con);

         $result = mysql_query($query);

         // THE ERROR IS REPORTED ON THIS LINE
         return $result;

}

          function buildQuery()  {

                    $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];

                    $sql = "SELECT * from movies WHERE
                            (
                            'movie_title' LIKE '%keyword%'
                            OR
                            'movie_description' LIKE '%keyword%'
                            )";

                    return $sql;  

        }

         $query = buildQuery();

         $records = getRecords($query);

         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){ ?>

 <tbody>
          <table border='1'>

            <tr>
                   <td><?= $row['movie_title']; ?></td>
                   <td><?= $row['movie_rating']; ?></td>
                   <td> <img src="<?= $row['movie_image'];?>"> </td>
                   <td><?= $row['movie_description']; ?></td>
                   <td><a href="movie_index.php">Return to Search</a></td>
            </tr>

<? }  ?>

</tbody>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Please post the rest of the error message. It is cut off in the question title.  Specifically, on which line it occurs.

Comment: To sum up: an undisclosed interpreter (PHP or SQL) is throwing a warning in an undisclosed line, so you've made some undisclosed changes in your PHP settings to no avail. Correct? ;-P

Comment: The rest of the error is:  C:\xampp\htdocs\movie_display.php on line 34

Comment: Yes, I made the changes to no avail. :-)

Line 34 is:  return $result;

Comment: @CherylAnnCE: Make your editor show you characters like spaces and tabs visually. 29 looks like a space, but isn't one.

Comment: Yes! @TomalakGeret'kal, there are some odd spaces in line 34. They appear to be random spaces, but are not deleting. I'm going to try deleting and rewriting a few lines in there and see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: you are searching with keyword but not putting the keyword as $variable, it's interpret as word in your query.

Comment: @punit, I think your advice will help me fix the error I'm working on right now which is: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\movie_display.php on line 42. But, I'm not understanding your suggestion. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Here is my form code:

<html>
<body>

<form action="movie_display.php" method=get>
<fieldset>
<legend>Movies</legend>
<label for="keyword">Search</label>
<input id="keyword" name="keyword" />
<input type=submit name=submit value=Search />
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Actually, I have defined @keyword...

Comment: i tried the exact code after doing some changes it's working for me , you should check your connection parameter and also improve your html structure for while loop.

Comment: Thank you, @punit. I was able to solve the unexpected character input error by rewriting a few lines to remove some odd spacing added by the software. Also, was not pulling from the correct source...rather, was trying to pull from the database instead of the table. All is working well now. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The editor had added spaces that were not deletable. I had to delete several lines and rewrite them. So, this issue wasn't exactly with the code...just a text editor software problem.

The other error I had was a boolean error with my query. Turns out I was trying to query the database instead of the table.

Thanks for all the help with this!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes from the column names in your query.  This may not be the only error, if the PHP interpreter is still complaining about ASCII 29.

```
               $sql = "SELECT * from movies WHERE
                        (
                        'movie_title' LIKE '%keyword%'
                        OR
                        'movie_description' LIKE '%keyword%'
                        )";

               // Should be
               $sql = "SELECT * from movies WHERE
                        (
                        movie_title LIKE '%keyword%'
                        OR
                        movie_description LIKE '%keyword%'
                        )";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea. I gave this a go, too, but the issue was actually with some spaces that were oddly placed by my editor and wouldn't delete. Free software. ;-P

Comment: Actually, I should have said that I fixed this. Thanks for pointing out this error, too.