# loop through dirs to see which are writable

Tags: php, loops

```
<?php
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./'), 
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->isDir()) {
        echo "\n" . strtoupper($file->getRealpath()), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

The above is what I have so far. I am looking to go through dirs and also sub-dirs and see which ones are write-able.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the isWritable() method?

```
<?php
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./'), 
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->isDir()) {
        echo "\n" . strtoupper($file->getRealpath()), PHP_EOL;
        if($file->isWritable()) {
            echo "directory is writable\n";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.iswritable.php

Comment: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=25) state=0

Comment: @user2002290 Worked fine for me. Did you use it "as is", or modify anything in the script and what is your PHP version?

Comment: @user2002290 what editor are you using?  Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839656/warning-unexpected-character-in-input-ascii-29-state-0-in

Comment: @MarkBasmayor (I know you were asking the OP) - I used plain 'ol Windows Notepad to copy/paste your above code and it worked fine. Although not the best editor, I know; I rather use Notepad++ for all other stuff I do.

Comment: @MarkBasmayor VIM you say. Never heard of it. Is it the one at `vim.org`?

Comment: @Fred yup, that's the one

Comment: @MarkBasmayor I thought so. I downloaded it the same day but haven't installed it yet. Am on Windows. Wondering if it has syntax highlighting/error checking for things other than `{` - `}` etc.? As in Notepad++, it will highlight the opening and closing braces for PHP, but won't (unless I don't know how) highlight opening and closing `"` double quotes etc.